# Mysql sort the results based on 2 columns from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sorting, left-join

I have 2 tables with the following structure

```
Products

id | name      | created_at          |
 1 | Produt1   | 2019-11-01 19:05:56 |
 2 | Product 2 | 2020-01-28 19:05:56 |
 3 | Product 3 | 2020-01-26 19:05:56 |

Draws

id | product_id |draw_number | created_at          |
 1 |          1 |          1 | 2020-01-28 19:05:56 | 
 2 |          1 |          2 | 2020-01-27 19:05:56 |
```

The scenario is, we have 3 products in product table and for product 1, we have 2 entries in draws table.

I am looking for a query here that selects the data from products table and data should be ordered by

1. If draws created_at exists, then order by draw created at
2. If no draws, sort by created at of products table.

Result output should be like this

```
id | name      | created_at          |
 1 | Produt1   | 2019-01-28 19:05:56 | //created_at of draws of latest draw for this product
 2 | Product 2 | 2020-01-28 19:05:56 |
 3 | Product 3 | 2020-01-26 19:05:56 |
```

How can I selected the expected data?
TIA

Comment: If you are using laravel, I guess `created_at` will always exists for every row. So, just add `order by draws.created_at, products.created_at`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, but how to order by the latest entry in draws table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Products t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT t2.product_id,
                   MAX(t2.created_at) created_at 
            FROM Draws t2
            GROUP BY product_id ) t3 ON t1.id = t3.product_id
ORDER BY GREATEST(t1.created_at, t3.created_at) DESC
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This give you the wanted result

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Draws
>     (`id` int, `product_id` int, `draw_number` int, `created_at` datetime)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Draws
>     (`id`, `product_id`, `draw_number`, `created_at`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 1, '2020-01-28 19:05:56'),
>     (2, 1, 2, '2020-01-27 19:05:56')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Products
>     (`id` int, `name` varchar(9), `created_at` datetime)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Products
>     (`id`, `name`, `created_at`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Produt1', '2019-11-01 19:05:56'),
>     (2, 'Product 2', '2020-01-28 19:05:56'),
>     (3, 'Product 3', '2020-01-26 19:05:56')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT p.id,p.name,MAX( IFNULL(d.`created_at` , p.`created_at`))
> FROM Draws d RIGHT JOIN Products p 
> ON d.product_id = p.id
> GROUP BY p.id,p.name
> ORDER BY p.id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name      | MAX( IFNULL(d.`created_at` , p.`created_at`))
> -: | :-------- | :--------------------------------------------
>  1 | Produt1   | 2020-01-28 19:05:56                          
>  2 | Product 2 | 2020-01-28 19:05:56                          
>  3 | Product 3 | 2020-01-26 19:05:56
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1193612ba9b98cb9fe0cd7c7a78ecf99)*